# How To Save A Public .txt File In iOS (So Any Text Reader App Can Open It)

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift, file-io

I know how to create a text file but it is only accessible within my app.

What do I need to add so this is a public document that any iOS file browser can find and open?

```
func saveInstructions(sender:AnyObject)
    {
        var savePath = fileDir()
        var fileName = "filters.text"
        var fileAtPath = savePath.path?.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
        if(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(fileAtPath!) == false)
        {
            NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(fileAtPath!, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
        }
        var fileHandle:NSFileHandle = NSFileHandle(forWritingAtPath: fileAtPath!)!
        fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
        fileHandle.writeData("text".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!)

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because iOS uses [App Sandboxing](https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/), other apps cannot access the files in your app (and you can't access the files in theirs).

The only way to make the files available to other apps is to use UIActivityViewController. This lets you export files to other apps. However, the file in their app is separate from yours, and any changes made in one app does not affect the copy in the other.

UIActivityViewController's documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/index.html) and a fantastic NSHipster article on the topic is found [here](http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/#stq=action&stp=1).

Comment: Interesting, I would think this would be such a common need. Sandbox ftl :(